# Session didn't saved my variable in an array: array(1) { [0]=> NULL }

Tags: php, session

My only problem now is that it doesn't want to save my session when I click my submit button. You can click on the following link to see my code:

http://pastie.org/6348801

Answer (score 0):

You never set the session variable (at least not in the code you provided), you only assign to $session an empty session variable.

To do it:

```
$_SESSION['productid3'] = 'your data';
```

Comment: thanks, $_SESSION['productid3'] has now a value and through var_dump I can now see that theire is now a value. But how can I show this session array on my page without loosing the session. Is that through for each? I did it like this but then I get undefined offset: if(!empty($_SESSION['productid3'])){




foreach($cart as $key){ 
   echo "<tr>";               
   echo "<td>".$cart[$key]."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$cart[$key]."</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
    }

      
}

Comment: Can you edit your first post with your updated source code please? I'd like to see how you set the session variable. Thanks